Pandas - How to extract a value into current row based on a previous row
I have a pandas dataframe with Column names Index, A, B, C, D
The values in column D have either positive numbers or negative numbers. If lets say the starting Index 0 value for Column D is a negative number, then it will continue in such a manner for a few more rows before switching to a positive number. Once it switches, it has the same pattern where it will have several positive numbers appearing in Column D before it switches to negative again.
I want to create a new dataframe and save into it the index reference every time the values change from either positive to negative in Column D or it changes from negative to positive in Column D. Hence in below example it needs to capture Index 3 and 7:
Index  Col D
0      23.3
1      24.4
2      43
3     -45
4     -54
5     -56
6     -89
7      89
8      90


The numpy.sign function returns -1 if x < 0, 0 if x==0, 1 if x > 0. The absolute difference between the return values between the two rows when the sign changes is 2. Use the series.diff method to find where this occurs.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sample = {
    "D": [23.3, 24.4, 43, -45, -54, -56, -89, 89, 90]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(sample)

df.index[df.D.map(np.sign).diff().abs().eq(2)]

Output:
Index([3, 7], dtype='int64')

Explanation of the dataframe operations:

df.D: Selects the column 'D' from the DataFrame df, equivalent to df["D"].

.map(np.sign): Applies the NumPy np.sign function element-wise to the values in column 'D'. The np.sign function returns -1 for negative numbers, 0 for zero, and 1 for positive numbers.

.diff(): Computes the difference between consecutive elements of the Series obtained after applying np.sign to column 'D'. Given that there is no zero value in the column, the possible results are -2 and 2, (Negative -> Positive: -1 - 1 = -2; Positive -> Negative: 1 - -1 =2)

.abs(): Calculates the absolute value of the resulting Series from .diff(). This step ensures that all differences are positive, so when the sign changes the result is always 2.

.eq(2): Compares each element of the resulting Series to 2, returning a boolean Series where True indicates that the difference is equal to 2, and False otherwise.

df.index[df.D.map(np.sign).diff().abs().eq(2)]: The final expression uses boolean indexing on the DataFrame's index to retrieve the indices where the condition .eq(2) is True.



Does this means that [-1, 0, 1] would have no sign change? ;)

Yes. There is no requirement for 0 in the question.

Thank u Dan for your response. It worked. If u have a moment Can i trouble u to please explain the methods u have connected up to solve this and what they do in this context

I've updated the answer to include an explanation of how the code works.

Code
When dealing with the concept of sign changes, it is important to clarify how to handle 0. Since there is no explanation in the text, I assumed that 0 does not exist and generated answer.
out = df[df['Col D'].mul(df['Col D'].shift()).lt(0)].index

out:
Int64Index([3, 7], dtype='int64')

Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Col D': [23.3, 24.4, 43.0, -45.0, -54.0, -56.0, -89.0, 89.0, 90.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
    Col D
0   23.3
1   24.4
2   43.0
3   -45.0
4   -54.0
5   -56.0
6   -89.0
7   89.0
8   90.0


Thank you. Your code works...however i am not quite sure i understand how it achieves the outcome. Can i trouble u to give a short explainer on how the methods are connected and how it operates at each row without the use of a for loop. Thank you :)

You can use a mask and diff.
If you want to consider 0 a positive number:
s = df['Col D'].ge(0)
out = df.index[s.diff().fillna(False)]

If you want to consider 0 separately from negative/positive, first use numpy.sign:
import numpy as np

s = np.sign(df['Col D'])
out = df.index[s.diff().fillna(0).ne(0)]

Output:
Index([3, 7], dtype='int64')

Intermediates
considering 0 as a positive number:
   Col D      s s.diff()  s.diff().fillna(False)
0      1   True      NaN                   False
1      2   True    False                   False
2     -1  False     True                    True
3     -2  False    False                   False
4      0   True     True                    True
5      1   True    False                   False  # 1 and 0 have the same sign

considering 0 independently:
   Col D  s  s.diff()  s.diff().fillna(0).ne(0)
0      1  1       NaN                     False
1      2  1       0.0                     False
2     -1 -1      -2.0                      True
3     -2 -1       0.0                     False
4      0  0       1.0                      True
5      1  1       1.0                      True  # 1 and 0 have a different sign


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = {'Index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        'Col D': [23.3, 24.4, 43, -45, -54, -56, -89, 89, 90]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
# Convert Column D to a NumPy array
col_d_values = df['Col D'].to_numpy()#df['Col D'].values

# Find the sign of each value in Column D
signs = np.sign(col_d_values)
print(signs)#[ 1.  1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1.  1.]

# Find the indices where the sign changes
sign_changes = np.where(np.diff(signs) != 0)[0] + 1

# Get the index references where the sign changes
index_references = df.loc[sign_changes, 'Index'].tolist()

print(index_references)#[3, 7]

